# Magento2 Create eav_attribute for catalog

Tags: attributes, eav, magento2

I'm trying to understand how magento2 is creating attributes in initial installation and using this I'm trying to create my own attribute.

For example I'd like to create duplicate of thumbnail attribute.

I followed the instruction in this article: https://www.atwix.com/magento/adding-attribute-programatically-magento2/

But I'm getting an error (I got error with report which refer to class below)

```
    <type name="Magento\Framework\Module\Updater\SetupFactory">
```

As I have no Magento\Framework\Module\ **Updater** folder. What am I doing wrong?

---

Then I tried to look how magento does it resolve.

I have opened Catalog/Setup folder and found file, which is creating attributes just like I need (Setup/CategorySetup). For example:

```
                'thumbnail' => [
                    'type' => 'varchar',
                    'label' => 'Thumbnail',
                    'input' => 'media_image',
                    'frontend' => 'Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Frontend\Image',
                    'required' => false,
                    'sort_order' => 3,
                    'global' => \Magento\Catalog\Model\Resource\Eav\Attribute::SCOPE_STORE,
                    'used_in_product_listing' => true,
                    'group' => 'Images',
                ],
```

this is a part of

```
    public function getDefaultEntities()
```

**But I can't find where does this method calls(1 question)**, as it runs only once when magento installs and it's impossible to put breakpoint

**2. Which file executes by default? Is it InstallData/Schema? Should I write anything in config to say magento execute installation script** (as it done in magento 1 in core_setup directive)

p.s. Any article on this topic will be appreciated.

Comment: `@Wojtek Naruniec i tried with code what you mentioned above , but it is now working also i don't find the Magento\Catalog\Setup\CategorySetupFactory.php file in the 1.0.0 beta version` by *user3404885 *

Comment: @zhartaunik second question remain as it is. Can you please give it answer for that or you found anything

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Place `InstallData.php` file in your module's `Setup` directory:

```
<?php

namespace Training\Product\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Catalog\Setup\CategorySetupFactory;

/**
 * @codeCoverageIgnore
 */
class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{
    /**
     * Category setup factory
     *
     * @var CategorySetupFactory
     */
    private $categorySetupFactory;

    /**
     * Init
     *
     * @param CategorySetupFactory $categorySetupFactory
     */
    public function __construct(CategorySetupFactory $categorySetupFactory)
    {
        $this->categorySetupFactory = $categorySetupFactory;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $setup->startSetup();

        $categorySetup = $this->categorySetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

        $categorySetup->addAttribute(
            \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY,
            'some_new_attr',
            [
                'label'            => 'Some Cool Attribute',
                'group'            => 'Product Details',
                'required'         => false,
                'visible_on_front' => true,
            ]
        );

        $setup->endSetup();
    }
}
```

Then add your module to `app/etc/config.php`, clear cache and install:

```
bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

This should be enough, no need to add anything in XML files. This should answer your second question.

Regarding first one, data from `Magento\Catalog\Setup\CategorySetup::getDefaultEntities()` is used by `Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup::installEntities()` method.

Comment: Thank you for your post. I have already resolved my issue. Vote for your answer as it can be helpfull for others.

Comment: Would you please explain if there is a difference of using eavSetupFactory instead of categorySetupFactory?